# Make option method of spark configurable based on a dictionary

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below Dictionary -

```
config = 
{
'inferschema':'True',
'header':'true'
}
```

Based on the above JSON config file, i want to create a dataframe by making  .option method of spark configurable. For e.g. the option method should look like below for above config and dataframe should get created like this

```
   dataframe= spark.read.format('CSV').option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `reduce` the dictionary items:

```
from functools import reduce

config = {'inferschema': 'true', 'header': 'true'}
reader = reduce(lambda x, y: x.option(y[0], y[1]), config.items(), spark.read)
```

Comment: Its not working. When i pass 'inferschema':'false' in config, it still infers the schema of CSV file

Comment: and a sample CSV file?

Comment: can you explain me what this reduce function is doing?Also, how will it take care if i have more than 2 key-value pair items also in config?

Comment: it works for any number of key-value pairs. The way it works is just looping over each key-value pair and appending a corresponding `.option(key, value)` to `spark.read`.

Comment: what is y[0] and y[1]. I am confused about this

Comment: what does x and y corresponds to?

Comment: Please read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) for explanations

Comment: thanks. Could you please help me in refactoring task for the same problem as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67226505/reformat-the-if-else-conditions-in-pyspark-code

Answer (score 5):

You can use `options` and unpack the dictionary.

```
dataframe = spark.read.format('CSV').options(**config)
```