# Reformat the if else conditions in Pyspark Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Can anyone tell me how to reformat the below Pyspark code especially the line  dataframe = spark.read.format(main.FILE_FORMAT).load(read_path) which is coming for ORC,CSV and Parquet file types? I want to take this common line out of if conditions and put outside so that the code becomes efficient.

```
    Config={'header':'true','inferschema':'true'}
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    reader = reduce(lambda x, y: x.option(y[0], y[1]), Config.items(), spark.read)
    if list(pathlib.Path(table_path).rglob("**/*.parquet")):
           if main.FILE_FORMAT == "":
               main.FILE_FORMAT = "parquet"
            dataframe = spark.read.format(main.FILE_FORMAT).load(read_path)
    elif list(pathlib.Path(table_path).rglob("**/*.orc")):
            if main.FILE_FORMAT == "":
                main.FILE_FORMAT = "orc"
            dataframe = spark.read.format(main.FILE_FORMAT).load(read_path)
    elif list(pathlib.Path(table_path).rglob("**/*.csv")):
            if main.FILE_FORMAT == "":
                main.FILE_FORMAT = "csv"
            dataframe = (
                reader.format(main.FILE_FORMAT).load(read_path)
            )
    else:
            raise RuntimeError(f"Could not find orc or parquet or csv files")
    
    return dataframe
```

Comment: as you said, can't you just put the line `dataframe = ...` just before `return dataframe`?  the `main.FILE_FORMAT` variable should survive throughout the `if`/`elif`s

Comment: reader.format(main.FILE_FORMAT).load(read_path) is only for 'CSV file' not for ORC and Parquet file format. How should we have just one line of code before return dataframe?

Comment: something like `dataframe = reader.format(main.FILE_FORMAT).load(read_path) if main.FILE_FORMAT == 'csv' else spark.read.format(main.FILE_FORMAT).load(read_path)`